# Admin two site with Multiple Site Manager

Tags: multi-site-manager

Is possible to publish an entry belong to domain1 in domain2 simply adding a channel field to that entry?
Something like:

**Publish on**

- domain1
- domain2
- both domain1 and domain2

I short can I have only one entries' database and choose where to publish them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a dropdown field (call it say, display_on) to your channel with the options *Domain 1*, *Domain 2*, *Domain 1 + 2*.

Then in your channel entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" search:display_on="=Domain 1" site="domain_1" dynamic="no"}
```

or

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" search:display_on="=Domain 1|Domain 2" site="domain_1" dynamic="no"}
```

You could also achieve this using categories instead of the dropdown depending on your content.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" category="1" site="domain_1" dynamic="no"}
```